# Virtual models in ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Is there a way we can define a virtual model in ecto. Which don't have `migration file` and `don't persist in the data base`. I didn't find any documentation related to that in Ecto docs. I need this to test some functions in the iex. To test with models separate from the rest of the app.

I found `embedded schema` which contain fields that don't persist in the database but nothing related to the models.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded schema is just fine.

```rb
defmodule Test.Model do
  @moduledoc ~S"""
  The dummy test model that is not stored in the database.
  """
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  @type t :: Ecto.Schema.t

  @fields ~w|foo bar baz|a
  @primary_key false

  embedded_schema do
    field :foo, :string
    field :bar, :integer
    field :baz, :float
  end

  def new(data) when is_map(data) do
    %__MODULE__{}
    |> cast(data, @fields)
    |> validate_required(~w|foo|a)
    |> apply_changes()
  end
end
```

Once defined, it might be used as the normal schema.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: The only caveat I'd add is that `apply_changes/1` ignores validity. In a project of mine, I created a `maybe_apply_changes/1` function that returns the `valid?: false` changeset for processing by the caller. Source: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#apply_changes/1